# Optimal way of displaying SQL-data in JAVA & C# through WS

Tags: java, c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a .NET WebService that I'd like to access through a WinForms and a Java application.

As of now I only get the datagridview filled rows and columns contaning probably the length of the string(?). And I haven't found a way for Java to interpret the List

I would like to be able to fill rows and columns in both the JTable in Java as well as the datagridview in WinForms/C#. Therefore I wonder if perhaps a 2d-string array is better, since I will be able to define both columns and rows?

**This is the asmx web-service c# class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace WS_ERP
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for ERPService
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://erpimlement.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class ERPService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        private DAL dal = new DAL();

        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public List<List<string>> Fill(string s)
        {
            return dal.ShowData(s);
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public List<string> GetEmpTbl()
        {
            return null;
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public List<List<string>> ShowAbsData() {
            return dal.GetEmpAbsData();
        }
    }
}
```

**The SQL is accessed through my DAL, see below:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WS_ERP
{
    public class DAL
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();

    public DAL()
    {
        con.ConnectionString =
"user id=cronus;" +
"password=cronus;server=DESKTOP-LAMR8JS;" +
"Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
"database=Demo Database NAV (5-0); " +
"connection timeout=30";
    }
    //---------------------- SHOW DATA METHOD ----------------------//

    public List<List<string>> ShowData(string s)
    {
        con.Open();
        string query = s;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,con);
        SqlDataReader result =  cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (result != null)
        {
            List<List<string>> list = new List<List<string>>();

            while (result.Read())
            {
                List<string> tmp = new List<string>();
                for (int i = 0; i < result.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    string data = "";
                    if(result.GetFieldType(i) == typeof(string))
                    {
                        data = (string)result.GetString(i);
                    }
                    if(result.GetFieldType(i) == typeof(int))
                    {
                        int integer = result.GetInt32(i);
                        data = integer.ToString();
                    }
                    tmp.Add(data);
                }
                list.Add(tmp);
            }
            return list;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Method invoked from application

```
            public List<List<string>> GetEmpAbsData() {
        string s = "SELECT * from [CRONUS Sverige AB$Employee Absence] WHERE [From Date] LIKE '%2004%' AND [Cause of Absence Code] = 'SJUK'";
        return ShowData(s);
    }
```

Below is the source code for the form.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ERPForm.ServiceReference1;

namespace ERPForm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        ERPServiceSoapClient client = new ERPServiceSoapClient();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            comboBox1.DataSource = client.GetEmpTbl();
        }

        private void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           foreach(List<string> list in client.ShowAbsData() ){
                for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
                {
                    string s = list[i] + "\n";
                    richTextBox1.Text += s;
                }
            }
            }
    }
```

As of now I only get the datagridview filled rows and columns contaning probably the length of the string(?). And I haven't found a way for Java to interpret the List

I would like to be able to fill rows and columns in both the JTable in Java as well as the datagridview in WinForms/C#. Therefore I wonder if perhaps a 2d-string array is better, since I will be able to define both columns and rows?

Comment: I suggest [edit]ing your question and adding more specific information, like an example of the actual output of the web service, and the alternative format you had in mind, and also code you use for populating the table based on that output.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I updated the thread with more info and snapshots, hope it clears it up a little bit more.

Comment: Now I suggest you read the [help] to understand how to work with the site tools. Always include code *in the question itself*, not in a link to some other place, and certainly not in an image! We can't copy and test from an image. And if you want to display an image, use the image tools, not the "code" buttons.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I realize now my post wasn't very good. I apologize and hope it's better now, thanks for the pointers! :-)